direct sum of general linear space
Let $U_1, U_2, U_3$ be subspaces of a linear space $V$ such that $U_2 \cap U_3 = {0}$ and $U_1 \subseteq U_2$, and $V = U_1 \oplus U_3$. We want to prove that $U_1 = U_2$.
I did the following:
Assume, towards a contradiction, that $U_1 \subset U_2$. This means there exists some vector $v \in U_2$ such that $v \notin U_1$.
Because $V = U_1 \oplus U_3$, any vector $v \in V$ can be uniquely written as $v = u + w$ where $u \in U_1$ and $w \in U_3$.
Since $v \in U_2$ and $U_1 \subseteq U_2$, and $U_2$ is a subspace, we can decompose $v$ as $v = u + w$ with $u \in U_1 \subseteq U_2$ and $w \in U_3$.
I know that there is no way v can be composed from u which is in $U_1$ and also cannot be composed from w which is in $U_3$ but can't seem to put my finger on what specifically is missing to complete this proof and reach contradiction. Any ideas? thanks in advance !

Consider $v - u = w$. On one hand, we know that $w \in U_3$; on the other we must have that $v - u \in U_2$ since both $v$ and $u$ are in $U_2$. By assumption, $U_2 \cap U_3 = \{0\}$, so we have $w=0$ or $v=u$. Thus $v\in U_1$, but this is precisely what you assumed to not be true.
